# How to correct the position of hyper plane in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, linear-regression

**My code:**

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDRegressor

alpha_lst = [0.0001,1,100]

outlier = [(0,2),(21, 13), (-23, -15), (22,14), (23, 14)]

for i in range(len(alpha_lst)):
    plt.figure(figsize = (17,14))
    k = 0
    X= b * np.sin(phi)
    Y= a * np.cos(phi)
    for j in outlier:
        plt.subplot(3,5,k+1)
        k+=1 
        X = np.append(X,j[0]).reshape(-1,1)
        Y = np.append(Y,j[1]).reshape(-1,1)
        clf = SGDRegressor(alpha=alpha_lst[i], eta0=0.001, learning_rate='constant',random_state=0)
        clf.fit(X,Y)
        coef = clf.coef_
        intercept = clf.intercept_
        y_min = np.amin(X)
        y_max = np.amax(X)
        hyper_plane = draw_hyper_plane(coef,intercept,y_min,y_max)

        plt.scatter(X,Y,color='blue')

    plt.show()
```

**My drawing function:**

```
def draw_hyper_plane(coef,intercept,y_max,y_min):
    points=np.array([[((-coef*y_min - intercept)/coef), y_min],[((-coef*y_max - intercept)/coef), y_max]])
    plt.plot(points[:,0], points[:,1])
```

**Actual output:**
  [image: output from this code snippet]

**Desired Output:**
  [image: Desired output]

**My questions:**

- How can I modify my code to get the desired output?
- What is the effect of outlier on position of hyper plane?
- what parameter effect the position of plane?

Comment: It looks like maybe the biggest problem is that the scales of the plots are different (and also the colors).  It would also be helpful if you mentioned what library you are using to plot with.

Comment: @Thayne import matplotlib.pyplot as plt                    

import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDRegressor

Answer (score 4):

Well you can try this code:

```
hypers = [0.001,1,100]

plt.figure(figsize = (20,16))

for j,lr in enumerate(hypers):
    
    outlier_points = [(0,2),(21, 13), (-23, -15), (22,14), (23, 14)]
    X = b * np.sin(phi)
    Y = a * np.cos(phi)
    
    for c,k in enumerate(range(5*j+1, 5*(j+1)+1)):
        X= np.append(X,outlier_points[c][0])
        Y= np.append(Y,outlier_points[c][1])
        
        
        #training the model afte updating the outliers
        clf = SGDRegressor(alpha = lr, random_state=12)
        clf.fit(X.reshape(-1,1), Y)
        Y_pred =clf.predict(X.reshape(-1,1))
        plt.subplot(4,5,k)
        plt.scatter(X,Y)
        plt.plot(X,Y_pred, color ='red')
        plt.title(str(lr))

plt.show()
```

Comment: why to reshape X here?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove your plotting function, and just create `y_pred = clf.predict(X)`. After that use `plt.plot(X,y_pred)`, which will plot the required hyperplane.